# How to automate card payment in mobile application using appium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I am trying to automate a scenario, where i need to enter card details like name on card, card number, expiry date and CVC number. When i am trying to send the expiry date say as "2318", by default it is accepting value as "23/8". Ideally it should accept value as "23/18". I tried to give space in month and year but still it's not working. Any idea how to automate this?

following is my piece of code :

```
 @Override
    public void enterCardDetails() {
        waitForElement(appiumDriver,enterNameOnCardEditField).sendKeys("test");
        waitForElement(appiumDriver,enterCardNumberEditField).sendKeys("0000000000000000");
        waitForElement(appiumDriver,enterExpiryMMYYEditField).sendKeys("2518");
        waitForElement(appiumDriver,enterCVCNumberField).sendKeys("000");
        waitForElement(appiumDriver,makePaymentOption).click();
    }
```

I am using following appium and selenium versions :

1. appium-java client : 6.0.0-BETA5
2. appium Desktop version : 1.6.1
3. Selenium java version : 3.9.1

Unfortunately, I can not provide any screenshot of the appium inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding following capability :

capabilities.setCapability("maxTypingFrequency",10);

Answer (score 2):

As per your question what you are seeing is pretty much expected and is a result of *validation error* on the field for *expiry date*.

Essentially, the *expiry date* on any *Credit Card* would consist of **`MM/YY`** format, where:

- **`MM`** field would accept *character sequence* e.g. `01`, `10`, `12`, etc
- **`YY`** field would accept *character sequence* e.g. `18`, `19`, `20`, etc

Now whenever you try to send the *character sequence* of **`2318`** the `js` involved for the validation **doesn't accepts** the characters and in absence of a proper *js validator* allows the characters **`23`** and **`8`** within the **MM** and **YY** fields respectively.

It's a pottential bug which may have escaped *Manual Validation*

### Solution

Send a valid character sequence as follows:

```
waitForElement(appiumDriver,enterExpiryMMYYEditField).sendKeys("0718");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Indeed i checked the scenario multiple times, and then i was sure it was not an escapee. So i reached one of the appium developer and he gave me the workaround. By adding following capability which i have posted as an answer, i was able to solve the issue. Thanks for your help. cheers!